# Perfect forwaring of auto&& in generic lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, decltype, perfect-forwarding

The next generic lambda is used to protect any operation which shares resource between threads:

```
    auto mutexed = [mtx(std::mutex{})](auto &&fn, auto &&...args) mutable {
        std::unique_lock lo(mtx);
        return fn(args...);
        //return std::forward<decltype(fn)>(fn)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
```

`decltype(fn)` is not valid for perfect forwarding. It is good for values and rvalues references. But not for lvalue refs.
Writing `decltype((fn))` will work with lvalue references but not with rvalues.

So the question.

How to make it to perfectly forward both reference and rvalue reference?

Example to make threads do not corrupt stdout: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KsWM6Pq6x

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using std::cout, std::clog, std::cerr, std::endl;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

    auto mutexed = [mtx(std::mutex{})](auto &&fn, auto &&...args) mutable {
        std::unique_lock lo(mtx);
        //return fn(args...);
        return std::forward<decltype(fn)>(fn)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
    
    int counter = 0;
    auto t1 = std::thread( [&](){ 
        while(1){ 
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
            // mutexed( [](int&&cnt){ cout << cnt++ << endl; }, std::move(counter) ); //FAILS HERE
            mutexed( [](int&cnt){ cout << cnt++ << endl; }, counter );  //lval ref works fine
        }
    });

    auto t2 = std::thread([&]{ 
        while(1){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        mutexed( []{ cout << "done long_operation_2" << endl;});}
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

---

### Working solution in C++11,14,17 and C++20,23

```
int main() {
    auto lambda20 = []<class F, class...Ts>(F &&fn, Ts &&...args) {
        return std::forward<F>(fn)(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    };
    auto lambda14 = [](auto &&fn, auto &&...args) {
        return std::forward<
                std::conditional_t<
                        std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(fn)>,
                        typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(fn)>,
                        decltype(fn)>
        >(fn)(
                std::forward<
                        std::conditional_t<std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(args)>::value,
                                typename std::remove_reference<decltype(args)>::type,
                                decltype(args)
                        >>(args)...);
    };
    int inter = 20;
    lambda20([](int x) { cout << "asdf20   x" << endl; }, inter);
    lambda20([](int &x) { cout << "asdf20  &x" << endl; }, inter);
    lambda20([](int &&x) { cout << "asdf20 &&x" << endl; }, std::move(inter));
    lambda14([](int x) { cout << "asdf14   x" << endl; }, inter);
    lambda14([](int &x) { cout << "asdf14  &x" << endl; }, inter);
    lambda14([](int &&x) { cout << "asdf14 &&x" << endl; }, std::move(inter));

    return 0;
}
```

C++ pre-20 solution 8 years old by Scott Meyers https://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2013/05/c14-lambdas-and-perfect-forwarding.html

Comment: The commented out return statement looks valid and is forwarding all the arguments. Please clarify what is the exact problem.

Comment: But it does not.

Comment: And you assert this based on..? We don't live in your head or see through your eyes, you **need** a [mre] when asking, and not hand waving a question.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around what `return fn(args)...);` is supposed to be unpacked to.

Comment: updated with ref to godbolt

Comment: With your update. the `// FAILS HERE` line _should fail_.  You are passing named variable `int counter` to a lambda that expects an `int&&`.

Comment: yeah, there is std::move

Comment: With your **new** update, the code seems to compile and work as expected.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: no it does not. it would be obvious that it cant work in such a way. The question is as clear as it can be.

Comment: You have several syntax errors here and on godbold. If you fix them, all works well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In C++20 and later

```
auto lambda20 = []<class F, class...Ts>(F &&fn, Ts &&...args) {
    return std::forward<F>(fn)(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
};
```

In C++pre20 : C++11,14,17

```
auto lambda14 = [](auto &&fn, auto &&...args) {
    return std::forward<
            std::conditional_t<
                    std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(fn)>,
                    typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(fn)>,
                    decltype(fn)>
    >(fn)(
            std::forward<
                    std::conditional_t<std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(args)>::value,
                            typename std::remove_reference<decltype(args)>::type,
                            decltype(args)
                    >>(args)...);
};
```

Example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    auto lambda20 = []<class F, class...Ts>(F &&fn, Ts &&...args) {
        return std::forward<F>(fn)(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    };
    auto lambda14 = [](auto &&fn, auto &&...args) {
        return std::forward<
                std::conditional_t<
                        std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(fn)>,
                        typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(fn)>,
                        decltype(fn)>
        >(fn)(
                std::forward<
                        std::conditional_t<std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(args)>::value,
                                typename std::remove_reference<decltype(args)>::type,
                                decltype(args)
                        >>(args)...);
    };
    int inter = 20;
    lambda20([](int x) { cout << "asdf20   x" << endl; }, inter);
    lambda20([](int &x) { cout << "asdf20  &x" << endl; }, inter);
    lambda20([](int &&x) { cout << "asdf20 &&x" << endl; }, std::move(inter));
    lambda14([](int x) { cout << "asdf14   x" << endl; }, inter);
    lambda14([](int &x) { cout << "asdf14  &x" << endl; }, inter);
    lambda14([](int &&x) { cout << "asdf14 &&x" << endl; }, std::move(inter));

    return 0;
}
```

C++ pre-20 solution 8 years old by Scott Meyers https://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2013/05/c14-lambdas-and-perfect-forwarding.html